# Vine growth around mesh with GeoNodes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, procedural, shrinkwrap

I was wondering if there is a way to procedurally simulate a vine growth in Blender using GeoNode, like this guy did with Houdini (link down below). if anyone has a clue that would be really appreciated !

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY5SjX3f-JA

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a curve around your mesh, manually or using a proximity node, and animate a Trim Curve node to simulate growth.
[image]

This is the basic idea, adding branches and leaves can be daunting, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your request explicitly requires this be done with GeoNodes, I'd like to suggest having a look at IvyGen if you haven't already.

It's shipped with Blender like some other addons, but is disabled by default. Go to User Preferences > Addons and search for it. After enabling it, it appears in the Create tab of the sidebar and (if memory serves) in the shift-A (Add) menu of the 3D Viewport.

EDIT: More info here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_curve/ivy_gen.html